# Center Highcharts tooltip in the middle of donut chart in a responsive way

Tags: javascript, highcharts, positioning, centering, donut-chart

In Highcharts, I know you can put your tooltip in a fixed position using:

```
        tooltip: {
          positioner: function () {
              return { x: 50, y: 50 };
          },
        },
```

But how would I center it in the same way that margin: 0 auto would center it? I am trying to get the tooltip text to stay in the middle of a donut chart. The solution is probably something obvious but I have yet to figure out what it is. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please add some more code and show us what you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of chart `plotHeight` and `plotWidth` to get access to current chart height and width and adjust the tooltip x and y accordingly as below:

```
positioner:function(){              
 return { x: chart.plotWidth/2, y: chart.plotHeight/2 };
}
```

A working demo here: https://angular-raebwk.stackblitz.io